# Are there any easy Read/write to file system from Metro Apps when the files are in nested folders

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm working on a application that downloads some files to the local storage for caching. The files online are sometimes in 3 or 4 nested folders and I would like to also keep this hierarchy in my cache folder.

Is there no easy way other then having to `(await (await folder.GetFolderAsync("dir1")).GetFolderAsync("dir2))` and so on? Now it's hardcoded with `dir1` and `dir2`.

What's the easiest way when the file path is a string like `"MyFolder/OtherFolder/lastFolder/file.xml"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static member function [`StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync) can be used to get a `StorageFolder` object for a folder given its path.

Comment: Next problem is then, when the file dont exist i need to download it. try catch around the getfolder and then i again need to do createfolder, createfolder create folder until i am at the right location. Would have been nice with a CreateFoldersFromPath